# Trying to capture signature on ruby on rails application using SignaturePad

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I'm trying to set up a signature capture in my ruby on rails application. I'm using [signaturepad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#api-ref) here, but I'm getting javascript errors in my firebug.

Here is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require build/jquery.signaturepad.js
//= require build/flashcanvas.js
//= require build/json2.min.js
//= require_tree .

$(function(){
    $('.sigPad').signaturePad({drawOnly:true});
})
```

My views are rendered using HAML.

```
= simple_form_for(@blah) do |f|
      .form-actions
        %p.typeItDesc Review your signature
        %p.drawItDesc Draw your signature
        %ul.sigNav
          %li.typeIt
            %a.current{:href => "#type-it"} Type It
          %li.drawIt
            %a{:href => "#draw-it"} Draw It
          %li.clearButton
            %a{:href => "#clear"} Clear

          %div.sig.sigWrapper
            %div.typed

            %canvas.sigPad{:width=>"398" ,:height=>"255"}
            %input.output{:name => "output", :type => "hidden"}
```

Whenever I run the application I get the following javascriupt error in firebug:

```
element is undefined

if (!element.getContext && FlashCanvas)
```

I don't really know where I'm getting it wrong, the files are being included correctly though. Any ideas here?

Comment: What is the stacktrace for the error? What happens if you insert this before the call to `signaturePad`: `console.log($('.sigPad'))`

Comment: Found out the error, forgot to enclose the signature in a div.sigPad, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ouch - I figured it out, actually I had to enclose the entire signature in a div with class sigPad. Thanks anyway